# Typescript giving Error on @click even in simple programs while using nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am getting this error while using @click in Nuxt3 with Typescript

```
Type '($event: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.ts(2322)
__VLS_types.ts(107, 56): The expected type comes from property 'click' which is declared here on type 'EventObject<undefined, "click", {}, MouseEvent | undefined>'
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Same issue here with nuxt 3.0.0-rc.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same issue. I was able to track it down to the version of `@types/node` being incompatible with the Vue version I was using.

The following two Github issues helped me track down a solution:

- https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1985
- https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/6855

For me, the only solution that worked was to downgrade `@types/node` from the version I was on (`18.11.0`) to `18.8.0`, and this resolved the issues I had. There was mention of using a newer Vue version, however, I was testing with the latest released Vue version (and the same version that Volar was recommending be installed).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to delete my package-lock files and nuxt folder before re-installing packages to get it work.